# perl: substitute character within all brackets

Tags: string, perl, character, substitution, brackets

I have this PERL string:

```
my $string = "['-1XA0.55B',40,100,DU(26,3,20),100.00, DU(26,32,99) ]";
```

and would like to substitute all the commas within all () brackets, to get:

```
my $string = "['-1XA0.55B',40,100,DU(26.3.20),100.00, DU(26.32.99) ]";
```

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: The safest way would be to use whatever parser is meant to be used to read that string, then edit the specific fields in question separately from the other string. Then use the parser to output the data in string format again. So, do you have that parser?

Comment: Good idea. Yes, I wrote just a little parser which does solves that issue. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the string will be in the format you have listed. The simplest answer is

```
my $string = "['-1XA0.55B',40,100,DU(26,3,20),100.00, DU(26,32,99) ]";
$string =~ s/DU\((\d*),(\d*),(\d*)\)/DU\($1.$2.$3\)/g;
print $string;
```

Output would be ['-1XA0.55B',40,100,DU(26.3.20),100.00, DU(26.32.99) ]

I am capturing the digits in the parenthesis and using the special variables $1, $2, $3 as part of our substitution.

Comment: Help him to understand what you have done. An answer with no explanation won't help him

Comment: basic regex stuff, not sure what there is to explain.  I am capturing the digits in the parenthesis and using the special variables $1, $2, $3 as part of our substitution

Comment: you can explain the regex

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code factory, It's a community. Make a minimum effort when you write your answer, a fortiori when the one who's asking is a newbie

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way. It first finds all the substrings within parentheses and uses the `@-` and `@+` built-in arrays to save an array `@substr` containing each one's offset and length

Then the array is scanned and `substr` is used with `tr///` to convert all the commas to dots within those substrings

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $string = "['-1XA0.55B',40,100,DU(26,3,20),100.00, DU(26,32,99) ]";

my @substr;
push @substr, [ $-[1], $+[1]-$-[1] ] while $string =~ / \( ( [^()]* ) \) /gx;

substr($string, @$_) =~ tr/,/./ for @substr;

say $string;
```

#### output

```
['-1XA0.55B'.40.100.DU(26.3.20).100.00. DU(26.32.99) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done rather simply with a regex substitution. But it will be limited to simple cases, and no nested parentheses or parentheses inside quoted strings, or it will break.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "['-1XA0.55B',40,100,DU(26,3,20),100.00, DU(26,32,99) ]";
$string =~ s/\([^()]*\)/$& =~ tr|,|.|r/ge;
print $string;
```

Output:

```
['-1XA0.55B',40,100,DU(26.3.20),100.00, DU(26.32.99) ]
```

What we do is simply to match a literal parenthesis, followed by optional non-parentheses, followed by another parenthesis. Then we take that matched string `$&` and perform a transliteration on it, changing `,` to `.`, then return it as the replacement part of the substitution. The `/r` modifier on the `tr///` will not attempt to change `$&` (which is read-only, so we can't), but just return the resulting string without changing `$&`. The modifiers on the substitution `/ge` says to match globally, and that the replacement part (the transliteration) should be evaluated as code.

This can also be done with more verbose code which may be more illustrating, albeit more complicated

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "['-1XA0.55B',40,100,DU(26,3,20),100.00, DU(26,32,99) ]";
while ($string =~ /\([^()]*\)/g) {
    my $pos = pos($string);               # remember where we were
    my $match = $&;                       # copy the matched string
    $match =~ tr/,/./;                    # alter the copy
    $string = $` . $match . $';           # reassemble the string
    pos($string) = $pos + length($match); # reset position
}
print $string;
```

Here a lot of the code is made to emulate how the substitution regex works. Note that we have to reset the match position in the end since we alter the `$string` variable, and hence reset the iterator. The variables `` $` $& $' `` refer to the pre-match, match and post-match variables, respectively. The match referring to the most recent regex match.